# Adding Additional Claims to Identity using IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to add some additional claims to Identity using IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory. I created and new class that extend the interface IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory and override the CreateAsync. I configured the service accordingly. In my requirement handler, I am looking for that claim, but it's does not exists. It could be something very stupid, but I have not been able to figure out why it's not working. I looked at the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-claims-to-identity-using-iuserclaimsprincipalfactory) Microsoft provided at the bottom of Add custom user data to Identity page, that did not help.

**The AddPermissiontoClaim class**

```
public class AddPermissiontoClaim : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApiUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AddPermissiontoClaim(
  UserManager<ApiUser> userManager,
  RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
  IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApiUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim("Permissions", "Read")
        };
        identity.AddClaims(claims);
        return principal;
    }
}
```

**Registering the class in the Startup class.**

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<ApiUserIdentityDbContext>(opt =>{
            opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConStr"));
        });
        
       services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfiles));
       services.AddScoped<ICustomer,CustomerRepository>();
       services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
       services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(opt => {
            opt.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context => {
                var errors = context.ModelState
                .Where(v => v.Value.Errors.Count() > 0)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors)
                .Select(v => v.ErrorMessage);
                var error = new ApiValidationError {
                    Errors = errors
                };
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(error);
            };
        });
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApiUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiUserIdentityDbContext>();


        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(opt => {
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Token:Key"])),
              ValidateAudience = true,
              ValidateIssuer = true,
              ValidAudience = Configuration["Token:Audience"],
              ValidIssuer   = Configuration["Token:Issuer"]
            };
        });

        services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApiUser>, AddPermissiontoClaim>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();
    }
```

**The requirement handler**

```
public class PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
        {
            var permissionsClaim = context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Permissions");

        if (permissionsClaim == null)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        //TODO

        if (permissionsClaim.Value.ThisPermissionAllowed(requirement.Name))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The goal is to accomplish something similar to what the below middleware is doing. It works fine with the middleware except that I need to access the database and get a list of permissions to add to the claim.

```
public class AddClaimsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public AddClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if(httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(PermissionConstant.PackedPermissionType, "Admin")
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
            httpContext.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should keep your `ClaimTypes` of `AddPermissiontoClaim`  same with the type in  requirement handler.

Comment: Check more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @MichaelWang I made that change. The claim still was  not there. I put a breakpoint in the requirement and check to see what claims are in there. It did not have the Permissions claims.

Comment: It seems you never add Permissions claims. Follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-claims-to-identity-using-iuserclaimsprincipalfactory) to check.

Comment: @MichaelWang thanks for you help.  I saw these steps. In fact, I copied the sample codes into the project with the same result. I had to change ApplicationUser to ApiUser since it inherit from IdentityUser. When I checked the claims, it had 8 - aud, iss, nbf,exp, iat, emailaddress, dateofbirth,givenname. Admin was not one of them. I am going to create a brand new project just so I can play around with this.